# Refer to static json data from javascript and grunt

Tags: javascript, pug, gruntjs

I have some const values, which are used throughout the application as well as by jade for static code generation.

I was defining the data in file (const.js) as below.

```
my.const = (function () {
    return {};
}());

my.const.testType = Object.freeze({
    main: {key: 1, value: "Main"}
});
```

I include this file with script tag, and the variables are accessible to my application.

But, I do not find a way to read this file, and access the data object, `my.const` in jade. For that, I have to create a json file and configure grunt as

```
jade: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    pretty: true,
                    data: function(dest, src) {
                        console.log(dest, src);
                        return grunt.file.readJSON('app/const.json');
                    }
                },
                files: [...
```

I use [grunt-contrib-jade](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade#data) plugin.

I cannot use const.js as it needs to be a valid json file ([api](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/grunt.file)). So, I have to keep and maintain 2 files (js and json) with same data. How can I either

1. read the js file (const.js) with grunt and access the data (my.const)  OR
2. include the data from json file, statically so that scripts below can acccess the data. Simply including json file gives error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :)

or is there a better way (any grunt plugin to generate the js file, ...). I cannot think any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using node js, in your `const.js` file, add at the bottom:

```
.
.
if(module && module.exports) {
    module.exports = m;
}
```

At the top of your grunt file, require the `const.js` file:

```
var m = require('../path/to/const.js');
```

And then, in your grunt configuration data function:

```
                data: function(dest, src) {
                    console.log(dest, src);
                    return m;
                }
```

Comment: +1, almost solved.. A followup question should address rest of the issue. Thanks again.